# Eclipse "HTML Preview" is not showing my changes

Tags: eclipse, html

First time Eclipse user here.  I'm using "Eclipse IDE for JavaScript Web Developers", Indigo Service Release 2, and I'm including the EaselJS library in my project.  HTTP Preview at localhost is my server.

My problem is that when I make changes to the index.html file I'm working on and choose "Run", HTTP Preview (running within part of the Eclipse IDE window) doesn't show the changed index.html file; it just shows the old one.

If I launch Firefox and give it the same URL (http://localhost:8080/static1/index.html, since "static1" is my project name), it loads the new index.html fine.

Is there some way of changing HTTP Preview so it reloads index.html?  I suspect it's depending on some cached version.

Comment: Does this happen when you force a build? Eclipse attempts to determine if a new build is necessary based on changes when Project > Build Automatically is set.  This doesn't typically detect changes in html files as an indication to rebuild.

Comment: Looks like I can't force a build - "Build All" and "Build Project" are grayed out at all times, probably because of what you mention about html files.  I've noticed, though, the Refresh button in the HTTP Preview pane, which does reload index.html.  Problem solved.

Comment: If you have Automatic builds enabled, those options should be off--at any time you're either fully built or already building, there's no need to manually kick off what should end up as a no-op.  You're editing the HTML file in Eclipse and not with an external editor?

Comment: @nitind I agree that's what is supposed to happen.  However, in practice at least with Indigo I have it often not build when I'm editing html or resource files.  It just doesn't detect it as a change to trigger the automatic build process.

Comment: @nitind Yes, I'm editing the HTML file in Eclipse and not with an external editor.

Comment: @Bill You have to unselect Build Automatically before the options become available.  Give that a try and force a build for test.

Comment: It's now three days since I asked the question.  I am wiser now.  For the edification of any future googlers who find this page, I'll note that when I am just modifying my simple JavaScript and html, if I have remembered to actually save my modifications, then just clicking Refresh in the browser is all that's needed.  There's no need to "build" again, as the JavaScript and html are just text files sitting there.  In the end, I appear to have favored using Visual Studio instead of Eclipse, but that's because of familiarity more than anything else.

Comment: So you're saying you just forgot to save the changes to disk?

Answer (score 0):

go to .html file, right click on it-->open with -->Web page Editor. . .
what you type in below panel it will reflect directly in upper panel . . . .
:>